# How to change wish list tab name?

Tags: magento2, translate

[image]

How to change that `wish list name`  to " `wish list 1`" .I want default name wish list name " wish list 1" not by edit option

Answer (score 1):

> app/design/frontend/{Theme}/{name}/i18n/code_ISO.csv

```
"Wish List","wish list 1",module,Magento_Wishlist
```

**Note**: `code_ISO` is your language code exemple: `en_US` for `United States` one etc ...